# how to multiply the even number in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to multiply the even number of my list using the following code:

```
L3 = [1,7,9,9,4,1,11]
L3 = [item * 2 for item in L3 if item % 2 == 0]
print("test ",L3)
```

but the new list contains only [8], why the other items are gone?

Comment: Because `4` is the only even member; all others don't generate a value thanks to that `if`. `[8]` is what you get when you multiply every even number with `2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following:

```py
L3 = [1,7,9,9,4,1,11]
L3 = [item * 2 if item % 2 == 0 else item for item in L3 ]
print("test ",L3)
```

Answer (score 5):

You left them behind in the original list.  You need a conditional to bring along the original value *or* the new one:

```
L3 = [item * 2 if item % 2 == 0 else item  
      for item in L3]
```

This chooses one value or the other for each element in the list.

It's a little more readable if you present the "non-changing" and shorter clause first:

```
L3 = [item if item % 2 == 1 else item * 2  
      for item in L3]
```

... and since Booleans code as 1 (True) and 0 (False), you can leave out the constant:

```
L3 = [item if item % 2
           else item * 2  
      for item in L3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using the bitwise and operator:

```
L3 = [1,7,9,9,4,1,11,2]

[(1-x&1)*x+x for x in L3]
#=> [1, 7, 9, 9, 8, 1, 11, 4]
```

Explanation by examples:

```
3&1 #=> 1
1-3&1 #=> 0

4&1 #=> 0
1-4&1 #=> 1
```

So, you can use `x&1` in an if then statement or use it directly a formula, as I did: `(1-x&1)*x+x`