# Sum the Even Values of a String

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, recursion, ascii

> In this Exercise, you will sum the value of a string. Complete the recursive function
>
> ```
> def sumString(st):
> ```
>
> This function accepts a string as a parameter and sums the ASCII value for each character whose ASCII value is an even number.

I know how to sum all the values but the even numbers part is challenging.

```
def  sumString(st):
     if not st:
        return 0
     else:
        return ord(st[0]+sumString(st[1:])]
```

I tried something but i am just confused at this point.

```
def  sumString(st):
     if not st:
        return 0
     t=[ord(st[0]),sumString(st[1:])]
     for item in t:
         if item%2==0:
            return item+t
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67278264/how-to-multiply-the-even-number-in-a-list

Comment: recursive version is not pythonic. https://ideone.com/5Nzmdh

Comment: @MarekR the task he has been given requires them to use recursion even if it is slow and non pythonic. Also I don't think that generators and inline if statements are something they can use anyway

Comment: @SollyBunny Yes I'm aware, I'm just pointing that put that this is not good way to do in python. In functional languages recursion is a must, but in python it is bad choice. I've provided pythoninc version in how it will be guide to do recursive version (to give a rod not a fish),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
def sumString(st):
    if not st:
        return 0
    else:
        out = ord(st[0]) if ord(st[0]) % 2 == 0 else 0
        return out + sumString(st[1:])
        

print(sumString("abcd"))
```

Output:

```
198
```

The ASCII value for b is 98 and the ASCII value for d is 100. So 100 + 98 gives you the output.

Comment: Okay, I see where I went wrong, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

When posting code which causes an error, make sure to include that error
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`  in this case.
No offense, but the code you have written is a hot mess. You create a list with the ord of the first char, then the output of the function.
I think you then attempt to check if both values are even (not needed), and then return the sum (which you dont do since the return statement is inside the loop).
To do this you only need to check the first value of the string, then hand the rest to the same function

```py
def sumString(st):
    if not st:
        return 0
    out = sumString(st[1:]) # get output of the rest of the string
    if ord(st[0]) % 2 == 0: # check if first char in str is even
        out += ord(st[0])
    return out
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that it's a mess. I even got confused at one point. However, thank you. I realized where I went wrong. I am new to this so I know that I definitely have to practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here a method recursive and non:

```
def recursive_sum_even_ascii(s):
    if s:
        first, *other = s
        value = 0
        if not ord(first) % 2:
           value = ord(first)
        return value + recursive_sum_even_ascii(other)
    return 0


def sum_even_ascii(s):
    return sum(ord(char) for char in s if not ord(char) % 2)


# test
s = "23" 

out_rec = recursive_sum_even_ascii(s)
out = sum_even_ascii(s)

print(out_rec == out)
```